# Laravel : FatalErrorException

Tags: php, laravel

I have a log in page in my Laravel application which worked in local, but on the production server, I got the below error message (laravel.log)

```
[2014-05-21 01:07:31] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected '['' in /home/users/xxxx/web/xxxxxm/app/storage/views/8d74d14da5e7fbd7b4984adefddd5a1b:24
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

Code generated in **app/storage/views/8d74d14da5e7fbd7b4984adefddd5a1b** is:

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo Form::submit('save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']); ?>
</div>
...
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code

```
echo Form::submit('save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
```

You have used `[]` for array and in your server the version of `PHP` is probably lower than `5.4`. Check the version on your server or try changing the `[]` to `array()`.

Comment: I thought it was available in PHP 4.3 ..... Thank you @WereWolf ! I will validate your answer (as soon as stackoverflow allow me to do it :) )